# Managing memory in objective-C for auto properties set as (retain)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I'm not using garbage collection and I have a auto property set as retain. Should I release the object in my dealloc or does the generated code handle that for me.

More clearly, will the following code leak memory if I don't release `name` in dealloc.

*Person.h*

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
}
@property (retain) NSString* name;
@end
```

*Person.m*

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `retain`/`assign`/`copy` attributes of a `@property` only affects how they would behave in the getter and setter. You do need to manually `-release` the ivar in `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

yes this will create memory leak.

You should release it manually or in dealloc to prevent memory leak.

Here is another way to work with this..

//.h file

@interface Person : NSObject
{

NSString* name;

}

@end

//.m file

## import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

-(void)ViewdidLoad

{

//You can use this by self.name=[Nsstring StringWithFormat:@""];

}
@end

Thanks
Shyam Parmar